# How to check if a column has all null values in a table? snowflake sql

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to see if in my table there exists a column where the entirety of its rows are null.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName 
  WHERE yourSpecificColumnName IS NULL
```

-> this will only return the values that are null but i wont know if yourSpecificColumnName is entirely null throughout the table

Answer (score 0):

Using [COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count.html) combined with `HAVING`:

> COUNT
>
> **Returns either the number of non-NULL records for the specified columns**, or the total number of records.

```
SELECT 'Entire_column_is_empty'
FROM yourTable
HAVING COUNT(yourSpecificColumnName) = 0;
```

or `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
QUALIFY COUNT(yourSpecificColumnName) OVER() = 0;
```

---

Alternative approach:

```
SELECT 'Entire_column_is_empty'
FROM yourTable
HAVING MIN(yourSpecificColumnName) = MAX(yourSpecificColumnName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT to get all of the unique values of a column.
If only null returns, your column contains only nulls.